# Is that possible to show video picker like photo taker in windows?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, video

I need to display the videos and select only videos from the gallery, just like phototaker in wp.

Is that possible in windows phone?

I have also googled, but couldn't find any class available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is not possible as of now. We already tried to do this.

Also we checked the other applications like Whatsapp and viber which are top in market now, they are also not using it video selector. Since they have the video selector in all other platforms.